# Is there a difference between saying "Members are" and "All members are"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which is grammatically correct and why?

1. Members are requested to pay their subscriptions in time.
2. All the Members are requested to pay their subscriptions in time.

Comment: You forgot 1½) All Members are...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first is a request, the second a description of procedure.

Comment: It may be succinct, but I see little justification for this distinction. Either utterance can be interpreted either way.

Comment: Neo, the second is the same as the first one, with the exception of 'All the'. Both are requests. You have nothing to back up your claim that the first is a request and the second is somehow a description.

Comment: Souta: I'll back him up.  "Customers / Passengers / Members are requested to ...." is a commonly used way to give polite, formal instructions.

Comment: It's a subtle (and therefore subjective) difference, but I still see this as correct. Though perhaps adding `of procedure` to the end is even more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatically correct, but they are used in different contexts.

---

> Members are requested to ....

is a very formal, polite way to give an order.  You often hear it on aircraft, e.g.:

> Passengers are requested to return to their seats, fasten their seatbelts, and return their seats to the upright position.

This is probably the form that you should be using.

---

> All the members are requested to ...

is not usually used to give instructions.  You are just describing the situation.  E.g.:

> All the members are requested to pay their subscriptions on time, but more than 20% pay late.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a grammar problem but a semantics question:

> *Is there a difference between saying "**Members are**" and "**All members are**"?*

I think the default assumption is that they are equivalent, unless it's common and accepted practice in the club for **some** members to pay their dues late.

I also think the phrase ***in** time* should be changed to ***on** time*. The former phrase means to do something before something else happens, e.g.,

> *Be at the station **in time** to find a seat on the train or you'll have to stand.*

The latter means to do something before the deadline, i.e., in a timely manner, e.g.,

> *Please pay your dues **on time**. If you're late too often, you will be asked to pay a 10% surcharge.*

Comment: "In time" can also mean "not right now but at some unspecified time in the future". As in, "I can't do it right now, but I'll get around to it in time." I suspect that is rather the opposite of the intended meaning here!

Comment: @Jay: Yes, it can mean "_eventually_", but I agree that it's not what _in time_ in the OP's question means.

Comment: Years ago when I was a member of the Procrastinator's Club, they did have a 10% penalty if you paid your dues on time. :-)

Comment: Aha! A special case.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using *members*, the sentence addresses the group of people comprising members as a unit.

Using *all members*, on the other hand, addresses individual members.

The difference, as Bill Franke has noted, is not one of grammar but semantics. It may be important, say, from a protocol point of view.